# ng-repeat is causing menu to not work

Tags: angularjs

I am creating dynamic menu using ng-repeat in angular 
my static code before using ng-repeat(with static content) is as below(which works perfectly fine. when we click honeymoon packages it opens child menu with options)

```
<nav class="cd-nav">
    <ul id="cd-primary-nav" class="cd-primary-nav is-fixed">
        <li class="has-children">
            <a href="#">Honeymoon Packages</a>

            <ul class="cd-secondary-nav is-hidden">
                <li class="go-back"><a href="#0">Menu</a></li>

                <li class="has-children">
                    <a href="#">Domestic Tour</a>

                    <ul class="is-hidden">
                        <li class="go-back"><a href="#0">Domestic Tour</a></li>
                        <li class="see-all"><a href="#">All Accessories</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Goa </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Shimla</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Jammu & Kashmir</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Himachal</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Malvan</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Bangal</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="has-children">
                    <a href="#">Bottoms</a>

                    <ul class="is-hidden">
                        <li class="go-back"><a href="#0">Clothing</a></li>
                        <li class="see-all"><a href="#">All Bottoms</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Casual Trousers</a></li>

                        <li><a href="#0">Leggings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#0">Shorts</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>


            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
</nav>
```

after using ng-repeat the code is as follows

```
<nav class="cd-nav">
    <ul id="cd-primary-nav" class="cd-primary-nav is-fixed">
        <li class="has-children" ng-repeat="category in listCategory">
            <a href="#" id="mainCat" target="_self">{{category.Name}}</a>


            <ul class="cd-secondary-nav is-hidden">
                <li class="go-back"><a href="#0">Menu</a></li>

                <li class="has-children">
                    <a href="#">Domestic Tour</a>

                    <ul class="is-hidden">
                        <li class="go-back"><a href="#0">Domestic Tour</a></li>
                        <li class="see-all"><a href="#">All Accessories</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Goa </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Shimla</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Jammu & Kashmir</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Himachal</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Malvan</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Bangal</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="has-children">
                    <a href="#">Bottoms</a>

                    <ul class="is-hidden">
                        <li class="go-back"><a href="#0">Clothing</a></li>
                        <li class="see-all"><a href="#">All Bottoms</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Casual Trousers</a></li>

                        <li><a href="#0">Leggings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#0">Shorts</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>


            </ul>
        </li>


    </ul>
</nav>
```

-[without ng-repeat] [image]

-[with ng-repeat not able to click and open submenu] [image]

but the sublist menu is not showing up after binding dynamic data using ng-repeat   can anybody please guid me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: what is the logic behind opening that `ul`, `li`, how you open that?

Comment: when we click the a href tag <a href="#">Honeymoon Packages</a>
the internal ul <ul class="cd-secondary-nav is-hidden"> is made visible making it appear like submenu 
which is working fine when static i.e. classes are getting passed as we click and we get desired output
but it doesnt work as we make it dynamic with ng-repeat

Comment: si you might have used some `script` or `css` tro open `submenu`?

Comment: If you used some script/plugin for that menu maybe it's loaded before content and than you need to reinitilized or refresh that plugin, I have te same problem with my menu.

Comment: @Sravan please find my plunker http://embed.plnkr.co/xzN9OUxWDPHa8gTtXrCq/   please open in full screen to observe the same

Comment: @KadirBušatlić please check my plukr (open in full screen) after using ng repeat how to reinitilized the used js and css..pls let me know thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check weather your `listCategory` in your controller is binding correctly.

I added solution to [codepen](https://codepen.io/lakmi/pen/RJoxGX)

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    
     $scope.listCategory = [
        {"Name" : "Honeymoon Packages" },
        {"Name" : "Honeymoon Packages2"},
        {"Name" : "Honeymoon Packages3"},
        {"Name" : "Honeymoon Packages4"},
        {"Name" : "Honeymoon Packages5"},
        {"Name" : "Honeymoon Packages6"},
        {"Name" : "Honeymoon Packages7"}
    ];
});
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <!---BOOTSRAP JS AND CSS-------->
  <script src="jquery-2.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- added angularjs -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <!---MEGA MENU---->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="mega-menu.css">
  <!-- Resource style -->
  <script src="modernizr.js"></script>
  <!-- Modernizr -->

  <!-----MEGA MENU SCRIPT------>
  <script src="jquery.mobile.custom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>  
  <!-- added app.js -->
  <script src="app.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <!---Navigation---->
  <header class="cd-main-header">
    <a class="cd-logo" href="#0"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo"></a>

    <ul class="cd-header-buttons">

      <li><a class="cd-nav-trigger" href="#cd-primary-nav"><span></span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- cd-header-buttons -->
  </header>

 <nav class="cd-nav">
    <ul id="cd-primary-nav" class="cd-primary-nav is-fixed">
        <li class="has-children" ng-repeat="category in listCategory">
            <a href="#" id="mainCat" target="_self">{{category.Name}}</a>

            <ul class="cd-secondary-nav is-hidden">
                <li class="go-back"><a href="#0">Menu</a></li>

                <li class="has-children">
                    <a href="#">Domestic Tour</a>

                    <ul class="is-hidden">
                        <li class="go-back"><a href="#0">Domestic Tour</a></li>
                        <li class="see-all"><a href="#">All Accessories</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Goa </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Shimla</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Jammu & Kashmir</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Himachal</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Malvan</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Bangal</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="has-children">
                    <a href="#">Bottoms</a>

                    <ul class="is-hidden">
                        <li class="go-back"><a href="#0">Clothing</a></li>
                        <li class="see-all"><a href="#">All Bottoms</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Casual Trousers</a></li>

                        <li><a href="#0">Leggings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#0">Shorts</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
  <!-- cd-nav -->
  <main class="cd-main-content">
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes it is binding correctly and displaying those menus viz. honeymoon package, adventure package etc. with ng-repeat

Comment: please find my plunker embed.plnkr.co/xzN9OUxWDPHa8gTtXrCq please open in full screen to observe the same this is before i use ng-repeat

Comment: @user9912741 I update my answer. you need to add angular library and app.js in your code. I tried but I couldn't update your code in plnkr. sorry for that.

Comment: i have done those steps to use ng-repeat directive to make it dynamic but after doing the same, the  main menues are not clickable and do not fire up submenus pls see the images for more details one without angular and one with angular...thanks

Comment: when i have $scope.listCategory1 = [
     "Honeymoon Packages" , "packag2"]; i.e. initialised with hard coded array it is working fine but as i am fetching those from db using a webservice it is binding and when i click a menu option it is taking me to localhost:1234/#  page :(

Comment: @user9912741 you need to set url instead of #,  _a href="#"_

Comment: I am talking about <a href="#" id="mainCat" target="_self">{{category.Name}}</a> instead of showing submenu i.e. domestic etc. it is taking me to another page. and if i some how avoid that by removing # from href it is not at all showing me the submenus....i.e. it is not updating the css and not doing show hide when i bind the data from web service...sorry and thanks

Comment: Would like to thank u for all your efforts u put to get me to resolve the problem. The cultprit was the main.js js code which has to be initialized after ng-repeat is done rendering. using on-finish-render i could  achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

As I am able to see that you have given id="mainCat" to your main menu and I think you know that id is unique in the view. So it will not click at all. Please try to give a unique id to all your tabs. You can use $index to do so.

```
   id="mainCat{{$index}}"
```

it will create a unique id. Hope this may help.